# rails haml ugly weird behaviour

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I have the following helper:

```
def feeder value=true
  if feeder? == value
    haml_tag :span, :<, :class => 'selected' do
      yield
    end
  else
    yield
  end
end
```

And the following in a view:

```
- feeder(false) do
  = link_to 'Leda', :root
```

This works as expected in haml non-ugly mode (development environment == haml indented code).
However in production mode (e.g. haml ugly rendering) i get this html:

```
<h1> 
<a href="/leda/">Leda</a> 
<!-- THIS SHOULD NOT BE HERE >>> -->
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<meta charset='utf-8'> 
<title>Feeder</title> 
<meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token"/> 
<meta name="csrf-token" content="8kp4xt6ZJU2nL5uLgVBW6BcB/RTA75QwynKvZTMtNF8="/> 
<link href="/leda/stylesheets/jquery-ui/smoothness/jquery-ui.css?1297978005" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
<link href="/leda/stylesheets/admin.css?1298951622" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
<script src="/leda/javascripts/jquery.js?1297978005" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/leda/javascripts/jquery-ui.js?1297978004" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/leda/javascripts/rails.js?1297978005" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/leda/javascripts/application.js?1300153136" type="text/javascript"></script> 

</head> 
<body> 
<div id='wrapper'> 
<div id='header'> 
<h1> 
<a href="/leda/">Leda</a> 
<!-- <<< END -->
 &raquo; 
<span class='selected'><a href="/leda/servers/GVM-S1">gvm1</a></span> 
</h1>
```

Replacing the else clause with this:

```
else
  haml_tag :span do
    yield
  end
end
```

fixes the problem, but i can't possibly understand why/how. What puzzles more is that it only fails on haml ugly rendering mode.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just do it all in the view, like this?

```
%span{:class => blah.feeder? && "selected"}= link_to 'Blah', blah
```

(haml docs on this are right [here](http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html#class-and-id-attributes).)

Your helper version seems unnecessarily complex.